# Можно ли использовать Date в new SearchCriteria

Tags: java, spring, jpa

код класса:

```java
@Entity
public class Player {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Race race;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Profession profession;
    private Integer experience;
    private Integer level;
    private Integer untilNextLevel;
    private Date birthday; // проблемное поле
    private Boolean banned;
```

```
PlayerService
        if (minExperience != null) {
            playerSpecification.add(new SearchCriteria("experience", minExperience, SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL));
        }
        if (maxExperience != null) {
            playerSpecification.add(new SearchCriteria("experience", maxExperience, SearchOperation.LESS_THAN_EQUAL));
        }
        // TODO скорректировать вызов, чтобы не возникало исключения
        if (after != null) {
            playerSpecification.add(new SearchCriteria("birthday", new Date(), SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL));
        }
```

Получаю исключение

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
Parameter value [Thu Jul 28 07:21:00 MSK 2022] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
```

Не совсем понимаю, почему оно возникает.
Дело в том, что в SearchCriteria передается объект и я передаю объект Дату. То внутри происходят какие-то магические изменения и дальше он эту дату преобразует в текст, а потом пытается снова в дату. И момент повторного преобразования в дату у него этого не получается сделать.

Comment: Простите, а можно приложить полный код класса или хотя бы отдельно блок кода с импортами. Спасибо

Comment: Судя по значениям в логе (Thu Jul 28 07:21:00 MSK 2022), смею предположить, что Вы пытаетесь использовать строковое значение для поля таблицы с типом date. Следовательно, копать надо в сторону того как указать тип для `SearchCriteria` и можно ли это вообще сделать. Ну либо попробовать передать значение даты в формате а-ля yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (чтобы проще было распарсить). `SimpleDateFormat`, либо что-то подобное для типов LocalDate Вам в помощь.

Comment: @МихаилРебров я скорректировал вопрос

Comment: @gooamoko , в том то и дело, что я передаю объект дату, а он потом преобразуется в несколько этапов (наверное). и затем снова из строки пытается сделать дату.

Comment: Вот чувак с такой же проблемой сталкивался https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61634368/problem-with-jpa-creteria-when-searching-for-date
Это был его единственный вопрос на stackoverflow :) 
Я не понял его решения. Он победил.

Comment: Кажется, стало кое-что проясняться. Мой класс SearchCriteria промежуточный слой по доставке данных для
PlayerSpecification , который в свою очередь использует
...predicates.add(builder.equal...
И действительно я в этом промежуточном слое сам делал toString, а затем уже эта строка снова пыталась преобразоваться в дату потом где-то внутри, сегодня позже снова буду рыть..

Comment: ```java
            ....s(SearchOperation.LESS_THAN)) {
                predicates.add(builder.lessThan(
                        root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                        root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.LESS_THAN_EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Был некорректно сформулирован вопрос.
Вот мой класс

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private Object value;
    private SearchOperation operation;
```

Я изначально думал, что это какой-то класс, наследованный от интерфейса. В поле "значения фильтра" можно сохранить любой объект.
Дальше экземпляры этого класса используются для построения Predicate через CriteriaBuilder
И вот в том моменте был косяк
Вместо этого

```
    if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN)) {
        predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(
                root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
```

Надо было писать так

```
    } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.DATE_GREATER_THAN)) { // date
        predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(
                root.get(criteria.getKey()), new Date(Long.parseLong(criteria.getValue().toString()))));
```

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся.